# SQL Rows with intended duplicate IDs - How to join them up?

Tags: sql, join, duplicates, string-aggregation, ssms-2016

I've got some user and department tables that are joined together, but with the option on the front end to include multiple "Leader" email addresses.

Ideally, I'd like to keep these separated out on the main dataset; however, on the reporting view, I'd like to get them all joined up.

How the data currently looks

| ID | Name |
| --- | --- |
| 157 | Bob |
| 157 | James |
| 300 | Phil |
| 300 | Keith |
| 300 | Paul |

How I'd like it to look

| ID | Name |
| --- | --- |
| 157 | Bob, James |
| 300 | Phil, Keith, Paul |

Alternatively in different columns, whichever is easiest.

Current code is similar to the below.

```
Select 
TU.ID, 
TUbyDept.FirstName, 
TU.LastAccessData

FROM USERDATA UD
LEFT JOIN DepartmentData DD 
    ON UD.DepartmentID = DD.ID

LEFT JOIN UserData UDByDept ON DD.id = UDByDept.DepartmentID
```

Any help would be appreciated as everything I've tried so far hasn't gone too well!

Using SSMS 2016

Answer (score 0):

If your *SQL Server* is earlier than SQL Server 2017 then something like this should do the trick.

```
WITH userlist (ID,[Name])
AS (SELECT ID,[Name] FROM YourSourceTable)
SELECT ID,
STUFF((SELECT [Name] + ',' 
    FROM userlist
    WHERE ID=users.ID
    FOR XML PATH(''))
    ,1,2,'')
FROM userlist users
GROUP BY ID;
```

I used a Common Table Expression because I am unsure how your original not aggregated/concatenated source code looks like. So essentially just replace "SELECT ID,[Name] FROM YourSourceTable" in my code with your actual source code for your 1st table ("How data currently looks").

You'd have a *much* easier time with SQL Server 2017 and later versions because they come with the STRING_AGG() function. [More on this on MSDN.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-agg-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#:%7E:text=STRING_AGG%20is%20an%20aggregate%20function,rules%20for%20data%20type%20conversions.)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a bit hackish and probably only sufficient for smaller datasets:

```
declare @x as xml=(select id,[name] from userdata for xml raw);
with distinctusers as
(
  select id from userdata group by id
)
select 
  d.id,
  x.t.query('row[@id=sql:column("id")]').query('distinct-values(row/@name)')

  from distincusers d
  outer apply @x.nodes('.') as x(t)
```